# Knowing $X \sim N(0, \sigma)$, how come $E\left(\frac{\sum X_i^2}{n}\right)= \sigma?$

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, expectation

Knowing $X \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0, \sigma)$,
how come $$E\left(\frac{\sum X_i^2}{n}\right)= \sigma?$$

I had already thought of using linearity. What I don't like is $X_i^2$.

Comment: Do you mean something like: "Knowing $X \sim Normal(0, \sigma)$,
how come $E(\frac{\sum x_i^2}{n}\}= \sigma$ ? "

Comment: Hint: the expected value is a linear operator. Use this to write things in terms of $E(X_i^2)$.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 5):

"What I don't like is $X_i^2$"

Hint:

$$E[X_i^2] = \operatorname{Var}(X_i)+(E[X_i])^2.$$